# setting variables with gnuplot's for cycle

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop, gnuplot

I am trying to set variables for gnuplot environment with **set for cycle** command. 
I am using 4.6 version and according the [gnuplot documention (page 70)](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnuplot.info%2Fdocs_4.6%2Fgnuplot.pdf&ei=9EHjT_yuEI31sgac1uzBBg&usg=AFQjCNGIBRhbpB8my3nC1akK7rLPFSWCKQ&sig2=hoNqqc-j-Kp0oJoCtZDO7w) the syntax is following:

```
for [intvar = start:end{:increment}]
for [stringvar in "A B C D"]
Examples:
set for [i = 1:10] style line i lc rgb "blue"
```

But i get this error:

```
gnuplot> set for [var in gpvars] replace(var,'#_#',' ')
                                 ^
         line 0: Unrecognized option.  See 'help set'.
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTDIRNAME="out"
TIMEFORMAT='%d.%m.%y'
GPPARS=( "xlabel "Time"" "ylabel "value1"" "y2label "value2"" "format x "%H:%M"")
GPPARS_MOD=()

for (( i=0; i < ${#GPPARS[@]}; i++)); do 
  FILE=${GPPARS[${i}]}
  echo "arg=${FILE}"
  GPPARS_MOD+=( "`echo "${FILE}" | sed -e 's/ /#_#/g'`" )
done

gnuplot << EOF
reset

replace(S,C,R)=(strstrt(S,C)) ? \
    replace( S[:strstrt(S,C)-1].R.S[strstrt(S,C)+strlen(C):] ,C,R) : S

set terminal png
set output "${OUTDIRNAME}/graph.png"
set timefmt "${TIMEFORMAT}"
set xdata time

gpvars="${GPPARS_MOD[@]}"

set for [var in gpvars] {
   replace(var,'#_#',' ')
}

...

EOF

...

exit 0
```

I am also using function replace, because spaces ( gnuplot ignores escape sequences )The function works flawlessly for plot for cycle.
I have tried with and without function and with variables without spaces, but the result is same.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're trying to set here...in a set command you need to set something (e.g. `set label` or `set arrow`).  What you're trying is akin to `stringvar="foo"; set stringvar` which also is a syntax error.

Comment: @mgilson The value for stringvar is from array GPPARS_MOD. 
So in the body in first iteration should be this:
`set xlabel "Time"`

Comment: I got it.  I'm writing an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note -- I'm not sure that I believe your bash array will group things the way you want it to ... for me, your quotations get stripped.   try:

```
GPPARS=( "xlabel 'Time'" "ylabel 'value1'" "y2label 'value2'" "format x '%H:%M'")
```

instead.  (interior double quotes replaced with single quotes)

This is a tricky one -- It's a good thing you're using gnuplot 4.6, otherwise I'm not sure how to go about solving it.  *(EDIT -- using gnuplot 4.4, you could use a combination of `word`, `words`, `if`, `reread`, `exists` and macros, but it's quite a messy solution)*

Note that what you have doesn't work because it is akin to:

```
MYLABEL='xlabel "foo"'
set MYLABEL
```

Gnuplot doesn't expand MYLABEL prior to doing the set command so that you can do things like:

```
MYLABEL="totally cool X label here!"
set xlabel MYLABEL
```

What you want *could* be accomplished using macros (but alas, not with iteration):

```
set macro 
MYLABEL='xlabel "foo"'
set @MYLABEL
```

But that doesn't quite work here either because macro expansion happens before anything else (e.g. function evaluation).  What you need here is gnuplot's more general iteration introduced in 4.6 combined with `eval`

```
do for [ var in gpvars ] {
    eval( 'set '.replace(var,'#_#',' ') )
}
```

**EDIT -- gnuplot 4.2+ solution**

```
#top of script -- Nothing should go here.
replace(S,C,R)=(strstrt(S,C)) ? \
     replace( S[:strstrt(S,C)-1].R.S[strstrt(S,C)+strlen(C):] ,C,R) : S
if( ! exists("N") ) N=1
TODO="${GPPARS_MOD[@]}"
set macro
do_set=replace(word(TODO,N),'#_#',' ')
set @do_set
N=N+1
if( N <= words(TODO) ) reread
#rest of script here ...
```

Comment: Thx! I will give you feedback in few hours

Comment: Unfortunatelly i got errors in both solutions.In first (for 4.6) i get `line 0: undefined variable: Time` For the second i get:`line 0: undefined variable: Time


gnuplot> N=N+1
            ^
         line 0: ';' expected`

Comment: @Rob -- The gnuplot 4.6 version worked for me right away.  Did you change the way you define the `GPVARS` array (in bash) like I suggested?  The gnuplot 4.2+ version had a bug where I wasn't calling `replace` with the correct number of arguments.  I've fixed and updated.

Comment: Yes, to this `GPPARS=( "xlabel Time" "ylabel val" )` But think i do mistake here inside gnuplot `gpvars="${GPPARS_MOD[@]}"`. To 4.2v I noticed that, so the error persists too.

Comment: Ha, ok with single quotations it works. I still dont get it why. But that would be a problem because these values in the array GPPARS are variables :(

Comment: @Rob To help you understand why `bash` is splitting your variables the way it is, just type `echo "xlabel "Time""`.  You'll see that the quotations get stripped.  But gnuplot needs the quotations ... I'm not completely sure what you mean about it being a problem.  You could probably also try the other way around `'xlabel "Time"'` if that makes it better ...